# Error when fetching NFT Floor Price using Rarible API

Tags: error-handling, fetch-api

My goal is to display `floorPrice` associated with the NFTs in a wallet. By using Rarible API I'm able to fetch NFTs in a wallet but when it comes to displaying floorPrice I'm getting the following errors:

```
origin 'http://xyz' has been blocked by CORS policy
 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Here's the API endpoint I'm using to fetch floor price:

```
https://api.rarible.org/v0.1/data/collections/{collection}/floorPrice
```

In the docs it states:

> required
> string (OlapCollectionPattern) ^(ETHEREUM|FLOW|TEZOS|POLYGON|SOLANA):.*$
> Identifier of collection

I am not sure how to go about sending the request as it is my second time using this API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not be sending the request to the correct endpoint.

The docs state the endpoint as:

`https://api.rarible.org/v0.1/collections/{collection}` - where `{collection}` is supposed to be replaced by the id of the collection that you are supposed to fetch.

`floorPrice` would be present in the response received, and would not be used in the API endpoint itself. Here's a sample fetch request:

```js
// assign collection id to collection variable before sending the request
fetch(`https://api.rarible.org/v0.1/collections/${collection}`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data.statistics.floorPrice));
```

`data.statistics.floorPrice` is where I think floorPrice should be according to the example here: https://api.rarible.org/v0.1/doc#tag/collection-controller. This may not be the exact format you are using for fetch, so use whatever headers/config helps you send the request.

Hope this helped.